# Standard sql: Total count and percentage of total count with several columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which I would like to use calculate the total count of each type for three columns(first scenario, second scenario, third scenario) and their respective percentage of total count. The table looks like the example below.

| unique_ID | first_scenario | second_scenario | third_scenario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | type 1 | type 1 | type 2 |
| 2 | type 2 | type 3 | type 3 |
| 3 | type 1 | type 2 | type 3 |
| 4 | type 3 | type 3 | type 1 |
| 5 | type 2 | type 2 | type 2 |

The result I am looking for would be something like the table below

| Types | first_scenario | fs_percent_of_total | second_scenario | ss_percent_of_total | third_scenario | ts_percent_of_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| type 1 | 2 | 0.4 | 1 | 0.2 | 1 | 0.2 |
| type 2 | 2 | 0.4 | 2 | 0.4 | 2 | 0.4 |
| type 3 | 1 | 0.2 | 2 | 0.4 | 2 | 0.4 |

I manage to get the total for one scenario, but I am not sure how to combine them all. Is there any way I can join to get the result I need?

```
SELECT
first_scenario AS types,
COUNT(first_scenario),
CEIL(first_scenario)*100/SUM(COUNT(first_scenario)) OVER() AS fs_percent_of_total
FROM my_table
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 1 unique_ID, 'type 1' first_scenario, 'type 1' second_scenario, 'type 2' third_scenario UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 unique_ID, 'type 2' first_scenario, 'type 3' second_scenario, 'type 3' third_scenario UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 unique_ID, 'type 1' first_scenario, 'type 2' second_scenario, 'type 3' third_scenario UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 unique_ID, 'type 3' first_scenario, 'type 3' second_scenario, 'type 1' third_scenario UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 unique_ID, 'type 2' first_scenario, 'type 2' second_scenario, 'type 2' third_scenario
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT type, scenario, COUNT(1) cnt, ROUND(COUNT(1) / SUM(COUNT(1)) OVER (PARTITION BY scenario), 2) percent_of_total
    FROM sample_table UNPIVOT (type FOR scenario IN (first_scenario, second_scenario, third_scenario))
   GROUP BY 1, 2
) PIVOT (
  ANY_VALUE(cnt) scenario, ANY_VALUE(percent_of_total) percent_of_total 
  FOR REPLACE(scenario, ' ', '_') IN ('first_scenario' fs, 'second_scenario' ss, 'third_scenario' ts)
);
```

**Query results**

[image]